# angular ng-repeat form.$error 'item' in 'item in collection'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm finding a way to automate form validation.
So I thought at this code

```
<div id="error-container" data-ng-show="(addContestantFrm.$error.length > 0)">
    <h6>Show errors</h6>
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="(key value) in addContestantFrm.$error">{{key}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**addContestantFrm.$error.length > 0**

I've no idea how to check the length of error collection

**data-ng-repeat="(key value) in addContestantFrm.$error"**

give me an error 
'item' in 'item in collection' should be identifier or (key, value) but got '(key value)'.

so is there to put my code working ?

Comment: You have `(key value)` in your repeat, as the error states, it should be `(key, value)`

Comment: ops thanx :) what about addContestantFrm.$error.lengt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addContestantFrm.$error` is an object, objects (`[Object object]`) doesn't have a length.  You could use the `addContestantFrm.$invalid` var, which already is a boolean.

Also, for answer completeness, I will restate what I said in the comment above:
You have (key value) in your repeat, as the error states, it should be (key, value)

Answer (score 0):

with correction

```
    <div id="error-container" data-ng-show="(addContestantFrm.$error.length > 0)">
       <h6>Show errors</h6>
           <ul>
              <li data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in addContestantFrm.$error">{{key}}</li>
           </ul>
        </div>
```